# Can same controller have two different File with two different max size limitation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've a controller method that takes two different file, one image file and one pdf file as input, can I limit the max size for image to 1MB and pdf to 10MB

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public String  createBook(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile coverPhoto,
                         @RequestParam("bookPdf") MultipartFile bookPdf,
                         @Valid @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, 
                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

I know spring can have `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB` this in property file. But I want dynamic size for each file. Is it possible in same method in same controller?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the file size or what?

Comment: @sonus21 yes. I want to validate both file size

Comment: There's no straight forward way to do so, you need to write custom validator and use that along with `@Valid` and set the `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` to the maximum size.